# Getting Carcassonne expansions 7 and 8

Tags: carcassonne

I have so far purchased all major expansions except expansions 7 (Catapult) and 8 (Bazaar), which I have not found anywhere (in any language).

Is the reason I can't find them because they are out of print?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because shopping questions are off-topic

Comment: Seems to me like a good enough question, since I can't find these expansions anywhere. It's not "shopping", I just can't find them.

Comment: @BobMorane I’m not sure I see the distinction. You’re looking for where to buy them, yes? That seems like a shopping question, since the only answer I can imagine is “Retailer X has copies of it.”

Comment: I've edited the question into something slightly different, but 1) it makes it into an allowed question, 2) it's still answered by the existing answer, and 3) it provides useful information (if not to the OP, then future readers). [The OP should feel free to revert the change, of course, but that will cause the question to be closed.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment (Feb 2018), [the publisher lists](https://www.hans-im-glueck.de/spiele/carcassonne-3.html) the expansion 7 (Catapult) as not available anymore. So your option would be to find this 2nd hand.

Expansion 8 is available at the [publisher's shop](https://cundco.de/erweiterungen/carcassonne-neue-edition/193/carcassonne-8.-erw.-bruecken-burgen-und-basare-neue-edition?c=76).